# Which attack stat does each starter Pokemon favour in Pokemon Sword and Shield?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I'm hoping to soft-reset for my starter Pokemon's Nature to boost it's primary attack stat, but I'm not sure which stat I should prefer with Scorbunny, Grookey or Sobble. Which of these mons are primarily physical vs special attackers? Or are they fairly mixed?

(Other family members are playing too and each is picking a different starter, hence I'd like an answer for all 3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grookey and Scorbunny are physical attackers, while Sobble is a special attacker.

Their final evolutions' Attack, Special Attack, and Speed are:

- Grookey: 125/60/85
- Scorbunny: 116/65/119
- Sobble: 85/125/120